# Fluent NHibernate - How to create a unique index on Upper(column)?

Tags: c#, oracle, fluent-nhibernate

I'm working with Oracle 12.1 DB.

I need a column to be case insensitive. e.g. if may table contain a 'name' column, and I inserted a row containing "TEST1" value, then when trying to insert "test1" I will fail.

The following SQL command does the trick:

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX name_idx ON MYTABLE ( **UPPER**(name));

**The question is - How do I accomplish it using FluentNHibernate (C#)  ?**

Map(x => x.Name).Unique();  // create a unique constraint, however it is case sensitive...

**Also - I'd appreciate input about the performanece of such an index**
Thanks

Comment: Those indexes are called function based indexes. I don't think you can generate them with Fluent NHibernate.

Comment: is it possible to create them in Nhibernate?

Comment: Based on a quick scan of the in-depth manual I'd say no. http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html